# HTML And CSS and Javascript: How to make a onclick even remove text in input text fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i made a peace of coding, but when i go into the login form and type something, then i go back into index, then i go back into login and the text is still there :O Please help me, my code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .vsible {
    display: block;
  }
  body {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 22px;
    width: 92%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  }
  .headers {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
  }
    .btn {
      background: #97cbed;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #97cbed, #0b5b8a);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #97cbed, #0b5b8a);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #97cbed, #0b5b8a);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #97cbed, #0b5b8a);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #97cbed, #0b5b8a);
      -webkit-border-radius: 60;
      -moz-border-radius: 60;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 15px;
      border: solid #1f628d 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 33.3333333333%;
      height: 50px; 
    }
      .btn:hover {
        background: #083c5c;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #083c5c, #83bee6);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #083c5c, #83bee6);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #083c5c, #83bee6);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #083c5c, #83bee6);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #083c5c, #83bee6);
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      #LoginDiv {
        width: 25%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 22px;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      }
      #RegisterDiv {
        width: 35%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 22px;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      }

 </style>

</head>

<body>


<div class="headers">

  <div id="IndexDivHeader" class="visible">
    <h1>Index</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="LoginDivHeader" class="hidden">
    <h1>Login form</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="RegisterDivHeader" class="hidden">
    <h1>Register form</h1>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="nav">

  <button class="btn" id="IndexBtn">Index</button><button class="btn" id="LoginBtn">Login</button><button class="btn" id="RegisterBtn">Register</button>

</div>

<div class="visible" id="IndexDiv">
  <h2>Welcome to this page</h2><p>Mycoolwebsite is a awsome site where you can do bullshit and drugs</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hidden" id="LoginDiv">
  <div class="visible" id="LoginForm">
    <center><h2>Login here</h2></center>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Username: </td>
        <td><input type="txt" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:300px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td><input type="password" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:300px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td></td><td><button id="submittedLogin">Login</button></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="SucLogin" class="hidden">

    <center><h1>You succesfully logged in!</h1><button id="ToIndexFromLogin">Go to home</button></center>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="hidden" id="RegisterDiv">

  <div class="visible" id="RegisterForm">
    <left><h2 style="width:142px;border:1px solid;padding:1px 1px 1px 1px;">Register form</h2></left>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Username: </td>
        <td><input type="txt" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:200px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
        <td>Real name: </td>
        <td><input type="txt" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:200px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td><input type="Password" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:200px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
        <td>Phone number: </td>
        <td><input type="txt" value="If secret type SECRET" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:200px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email: </td>
        <td><input type="Email" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:200px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
        <td>Age: </td>
        <td><input type="Number" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:200px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td></td><td><button id="submittedRegister">Register</button></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" id="SucRegister">
    <center><h1>You succesfully registered!</h1><button id="ToIndexFromRegister">Go to home</button></center>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

  var IndexDivHeader = document.getElementById('IndexDivHeader')
  var LoginDivHeader = document.getElementById('LoginDivHeader')
  var RegisterDivHeader = document.getElementById('RegisterDivHeader')

  var IndexBtn = document.getElementById('IndexBtn')
  var LoginBtn = document.getElementById('LoginBtn')
  var RegisterBtn = document.getElementById('RegisterBtn')
  var submittedLogin = document.getElementById('submittedLogin')
  var ToIndexFromLogin = document.getElementById('ToIndexFromLogin')
  var submittedRegister = document.getElementById('submittedRegister')
  var ToIndexFromRegister = document.getElementById('ToIndexFromRegister')

  var IndexDiv = document.getElementById('IndexDiv')
  var LoginDiv = document.getElementById('LoginDiv')
  var SucLogin = document.getElementById('SucLogin')
  var RegisterDiv = document.getElementById('RegisterDiv')
  var SucRegister = document.getElementById('SucRegister')

  var LoginForm = document.getElementById('LoginForm')

  IndexBtn.onclick = function () {
    IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
    IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
    LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
  }

  LoginBtn.onclick = function () {
    LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
    LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
    LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
    IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
  }
    submittedLogin.onclick = function () {
      SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
      LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    }
      ToIndexFromLogin.onclick = function () {
        IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
      }
  RegisterBtn.onclick = function () {
    IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
    RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
    RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
  }
  submittedRegister.onclick = function () {
    RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
  }
      ToIndexFromRegister.onclick = function () {
        IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
      }
</script>



 </body>
</html>
```

So heres the website: [mycoolwebsite](http://mycoolwebsite.neocities.org/).
So when i dont get this to work its REALLY Annoying!

And also i've tried to make a js script that refreshes the page without refreshing it. (Refreshing the code)

So if you want example, go into the link, then enter the Login page and type something than go to Register And type something, then back to login.. AND you see its still there.. same with register!

Comment: `Element.value = '';`

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: In the click handler where you want to clear the values from input. ^^^ is just a pseudo-code, use correct element in actual code.

Comment: Ill try do that, Thank!

Comment: Okay, i tried it. i put it with the RegisterBtn and it didnt work

Comment: `class="visible"` != `.vsible {`

Comment: @DanielAlder 
It didnt help that much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it been told in the comments, you should get the elements and set their value to ''- empty string.

```
element.value = '';
```

> Where to put it?

In the function that happens when you switch tabs, if I understood correctly its  LoginBtn.onclick

Just add it in the beginning for both the username and password inputs

Comment: Ill try that! Thank you

Comment: RegisterBtn.onclick = function () {
        IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'visible')element.value = '';
      }

Comment: element.value = '';RegisterBtn.onclick = function () {
        IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
      }

Comment: RegisterBtn.onclickelement.value = ''; = function () {
        IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
      }

Comment: RegisterBtn.onclick.element.value = ''; = function () {
        IndexDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        IndexDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginDiv.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        LoginForm.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucLogin.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        SucRegister.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
        RegisterDivHeader.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterDiv.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
        RegisterForm.setAttribute('class', 'visible')
      }

Comment: You shouldn't use element.value literally, element represents the DOM element you want to alter. Start by adding IDs to your username and password inputs, than use document.getElementById("the id").value = "";        on both of the user name and password

Comment: Thank you again, ill try

Comment: Okay i ended up with this:

var usernameLogin = document.getElementById('usernameLogin').value = "";

<input type="txt" id="usernameLogin" style="border-radius:10px; border-color:blue; width:300px;height:30px;padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;">

But still this made the Login button not work...

Comment: You should add the value = '' in the function, not in the html. Im sorry but im having hard times understanding what you did there

Comment: :P ok, but:
var usernameLogin = document.getElementById('usernameLogin').value = ""; is in the function:

Answer (score 1):

I will likely get down-voted for my answer here, however I hope the answer will assist. The answers given cover your issue,but I would like to suggest some learning and research into writing Web applications. From your code snippet there is a lot of inline CSS, and might suggest your JS could be simplified/replaced using CSS selectors.

Instead of hiding and showing elements based on state, you could look at using a CSS class to hide the content you don't want. This would make it much more readable and easier to deal with the changes.

Comment: It could work, but also it wouldn't... becouse if i was going to do that it would be harder to make contact with the database im going to use after the script is done...

Comment: A lot of the visibility toggling could be dealt with by using CSS classes to describe appearance and then using JS to apply these. This could also help make you code more semantic. Again unrelated slightly,  but as a newly registered user, maybe something which will be of assistance

Comment: Well.. if it did, it would take alot of time to recode my scripts. Thanks alot for actually commenting

Comment: The time you may face in doing it now, and in future, might help make the maintainability of your code much higher; therefore saving time

Comment: sure. give me a few moments and will do it when I get home

Comment: Okay thank you, is it possible to get a skype name? So i can ask for help more times?

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this, I will take a look later, been a bit hectic!